# Connecting to server using an SSH Config file

Tags: ssh

Given the following ~/.ssh/config file, why do I get a `Permission denied (publickey)` when executing

```
$ ssh entel.rancher1.internal
```

When this works:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa devops@172.0.0.4
```

---

**~/.ssh/config**

```
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host entel.rancher1.internal
  HostName 172.0.0.4
  User devops
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I've already validated that the permissions are correct:

```
$ ls -al ~/.ssh
drwx------ dj dj .
-rw------- dj dj config
-rw------- dj dj id_rsa
```

**Question**:  Why can I not connect to my machine via the ~/.ssh/config file by typing in the HostName, while I can SSH in using my private key with a bare ssh command?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are having an issue with the username. I think it is trying to log in as dj@entel.rancher1.internal

I suspect that the following would work:

```
ssh devops@entel.rancher1.internal
```

*Edited to remove information that was incorrect based on a typo in manpages*

Comment: the command does work, yes.. but I had specified `User devops`.  why would the config be ignoring this?

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: i've used SSH for years and have never seen this.  Pretty sure that `User'` is a typo, as you get a "bad configuration" in the config if you arbitrarily put that character in :)  any example out there has just `User theuser`

Comment: I just did "man ssh_config" on my machine and I can confirm that you are correct on that count.

Comment: I tested this with my own ~/.ssh/config and I found that your configuration works (with my own user and IP substituted in)  but with permissions of rw-rw-r--

Comment: your question is very helpful to the point where it's most likely using my username instead of `devops`, especially since `devops@entel.rancher1.internal` works.  so the root problem then, is 

> why isn't ssh abiding by the config file and using devops by default

Comment: Does the output of "man ssh_config" on your system actually include a "User" parameter at all? If so, I wonder if your config file is getting processed at all.

Comment: it does include the `User` directive.